# Path variable to mso.dll and msoutl.olb

Tags: c++, windows, ms-office

I'm trying to develop a toolbar for Microsoft Outlook. For getting it to work I need mso.dll and msoutl.olb as an import.
My problem is:  the path is hardcoded , but it varies for every OS and of course if someone doesn't install Office to the default path.

I tried it this way

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234788/en-us/

but it didn't work, because I couldn't get the return value I needed (OK, after four type conversions  but I thought there had to be a better way ;) )

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

The path to MSO.DLL is stored under the following registry key for Office 2007:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\FilesPaths\mso.dll
```

The install path is also under this key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\InstallRoot\Path
```